# Add value with no occurrences to table in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, levels

Say I have a range of exam grades in a data frame column:

```
grades <- c("B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F", "F")
grades.df <- data.frame(grades)
```

When illustrating this, the illustration would be a bit misleading, since it doesn't show 0 for a grade that everyone would expect to be there: "A":

`barplot(table(grades))`

How can I add "A" with 0 occurrences to this table, such that it would appear in the bar plot with zero height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `factor` with appropriate levels:

```
grades <- factor(c("B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F", "F"),levels=LETTERS[1:6])
table(grades)
grades
A B C D E F 
0 1 3 2 1 2 

barplot(table(grades))
```

[image: Example Output showing bars for each factor level]