# Slashes added to character strings in R

Tags: r, character

I'm trying to apply the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50609328/1872900). With a toy example, it works fine. But in my real data table, I run into a problem when applying `factor()` to the column data, and I think this has to do with slashes appearing in the character strings.

Toy example:

```
Eval <- c("Bad", "Bad", "OK", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Very good", "Very good", "Very good", "Very good")
my.df <- data.frame(Eval)
str(my.df[1])
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Eval: chr  "Bad" "Bad" "OK" "Good" ...
is.character(my.df$Eval)
[1] TRUE
as.character(my.df$Eval)
 [1] "Bad"       "Bad"       "OK"        "Good"      "Good"      "Good"      "Very good"
 [8] "Very good" "Very good" "Very good"
factor(my.df$Eval)
 [1] Bad       Bad       OK        Good      Good      Good      Very good Very good
 [9] Very good Very good
Levels: Bad Good OK Very good
```

The following is based on my real data (which I can't post online, as it contains sensitive data), called `real.df` here:

```
str(real.df[1])
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Eval: chr  "Good" "Good" "Bad" "OK" ...
is.character(real.df[1])
[1] FALSE
as.character(real.df[1])
[1] "c(\"Good\", \"Good\", \"Bad\", \"OK\", \"Good\", \"Bad\", \"Very good\", \"Very good\", \"Very good\", \"Very good\")"
factor(real.df[1])
Eval 
                                                            <NA> 
Levels: c("Good", "Bad", "OK", "Very good")
Warning message:
In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

My guess is that the problem is diagnosed by the unexpected output from the `is.character()` and `as.character()` commands, but I'm not sure how to fix this. I'm importing the data set with `read.table()`, and I've tried to play with using `quote = ""` as an argument, but to no avail.

Any idea?

Comment: `real.df[1]` is a dataframe (as your `str()` call showed).  You want `real.df[[1]]` or `real.df[, 1]` to select the first column.  (Beware if you use tibbles; the second form would have to be `real.df[,1,drop = TRUE]`.)

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks! Feel free to convert your comment into an answer that I can accept.